# Launch CKFinder in modal overlay from CKEditor

Tags: popup, modal-dialog, ckeditor, ckfinder

I've managed to integrate CKFinder with CKEditor using the instructions found on the site. However, the CKFinder popup appears in a new browser window. 
[image: CKFinder in new browser window]

The CKFinder site demonstrates [modal overlays](https://cksource.com/ckfinder3-net-preview/samples/modals.html) - but the examples are only for instances of CKFinder embedded in a site and not the one linked with CKEditor. 
[image: CKFinder in modal overlay]

How can I make sure CKFinder launched through CKEditor follows the same format. I'm unable to find any examples of the same on the CKEditor / CKFinder site or forums.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's how CKEditor handle custom file browsers.
Using [file browser API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api) from CKEditor you rely on popups only.

Using CKFinder's 3 modal would be possible if you'd implement custom plugin for CKEditor that adds that "Browse server" button and handles file browser by itself.